# Throw Exception if template.convertSendAndReceive consumer message handler throws exception?

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-amqp

I am using spring batch and spring amqp. I am producing messages in my spring batch ItemWriter using

```
public class ImportItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T> {

    private AmqpTemplate template;

    public AmqpTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(AmqpTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
        for (T item : items) {
            template.convertSendAndReceive(item.toString());                
        }
    }

}
```

and at consumer side, I am using POJO to handle messages using MessageListenerAdapter.

```
public class ImportMessageListener{

    @Override
    public String handle(String exchange) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Command Failed.");
    }

}
```

I want template.convertSendAndReceive(item.toString());    to throw the same exception thrown by message handler so that spring batch can stop the batch , mark it as failed and log the exception?

I had look at this but couldn't get how to achieve above use case ?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general mechanism to do that, although we are looking into it for a future release of [Spring Integration](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3371).

As long as your exception is serializable, you can send it as the result and test the payload type on the sending system...

```
public Object handle(String foo) {
    return new MySerializableException("Command failed");
}
```

And, on the receiving side...

```
if (result instanceof Exception) {
    throw (Exception) result;
}
```

Comment: How can I get Message object in handle instead of string ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240863/execution-of-rabbit-message-listener-failed-and-no-errorhandler-has-been-set-f