# How can we make producer in spring amqp rabbitmq waiting after sending all messages and release upon receiving all?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-amqp

I am queuing all messages to rabbitmq queue and processing those on remote server. Below is my producer and reply handler in same class.

```
public class AmqpAsynchRpcItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T>,
        MessageListener {

    protected String exchange;
    protected String routingKey;
    protected String queue;
    protected String replyQueue;
    protected RabbitTemplate template;

    // Reply handler 
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        try {
            String corrId = new String(message.getMessageProperties()
                    .getCorrelationId(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("received " + corrId + " from " + this.replyQueue);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Producer
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {

        for (T item : items) {
            System.out.println(item);

            System.out.println("Queing " + item + " to " + this.queue);

            Message message = MessageBuilder
                    .withBody(item.toString().getBytes())
                    .setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
                    .setReplyTo(this.replyQueue)
                    .setCorrelationId(item.toString().getBytes()).build();

            template.send(this.exchange, this.routingKey, message);

            System.out.println("Queued " + item + " to " + this.queue);

        }

        // It should wait here untill we get all replies in onMessage, How can we do this ?

    }
```

I am sending all messages in write method and getting replies in onMessage. This is working properly but write doesnt wait for replies, it returns to caller and spring-batch step is marked completed.

But I want the process to wait for replies after sending all message till we get all replies in onMessage. How can we do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any number of synchronization techniques; for example have the listener `put` the replies in a `LinkedBlockingQueue` and have the sender `take` (or `poll` with timeout) from the queue until all the replies are received.

Or, don't use a listener at all and simply use the same `RabbitTemplate` to `receive()` from the reply queue until all the replies are received.

However, `receive()` returns `null` if the queue is empty so you'll have to sleep between receives to avoid spinning the CPU.